# Unite 2 columns into a single one with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have two different columns with values:

Column1:

```
johg
michael
pesho
```

Column2:

```
sth
other
cofee
```

I want to unite these two columns like this:

```
johg
michael
pesho
sth
other
cofee
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `CONCAT` in MySQL if you want two concatenate values in two columns.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`column1`,',',`column2`)
FROM 
    table_name
```

OR are you trying for `UNION`

```
SELECT `column1` AS unique_col
FROM 
    table_name

    UNION ALL

SELECT `column2` AS unique_col
FROM 
    table_name
```

Hope this helps.